# Why does flutterwave standard code integration returns "Hosted Link" in console instead of redirecting to checkout page?

Tags: php, html, ajax, redirect

I'm trying to integrate flutterwave with php, using the code below. The code returns no error except "Hosted Link" in console. There is no redirection to flutterwave checkout page.
Please, someone with a better knowledge on how to do this should help me spot out the issue. I've been on this for hours.

```
if(!empty($post)){
        
        $curl = curl_init();

        $register_id = $register_id;
        $fullname = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['fullname']);
        $phoneno = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['phoneno']);
        $whatsappno = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['whatsappno']);
        $email = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $courseselected = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['courseselected']);
        $tr_amount = $this->con->real_escape_string($_POST['amount']);
        $registerdate = $date;
        $paymentStatus = "pending";
        $currency = "NGN";

            $txref = "rave" . uniqid(); // ensure you generate unique references per transaction.
            // get your public key from the dashboard.
            $PBFPubKey = "FLWPUBK-324f26e3fb7484592d0fee10ea07b767-X"; 
            $redirect_url = "https://localhost/bnbtechonlinetrainingregistration/user/status.php?email=$email&amount=$tr_amount"; // Set your own redirect URL

            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.ravepay.co/flwv3-pug/getpaidx/api/v2/hosted/pay",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
                'amount'=>$tr_amount,
                'customer_email'=>$email,
                'currency'=>$currency,
                'txref'=>$txref,
                'PBFPubKey'=>$PBFPubKey,
                'redirect_url'=>$redirect_url,
            ]),
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                "content-type: application/json",
                "cache-control: no-cache"
            ],
            ));

            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $err = curl_error($curl);

            if($err){
            // there was an error contacting the rave API
            die('Curl returned error: ' . $err);
            }

            $transaction = json_decode($response);

            if(!$transaction->data && !$transaction->data->link){
            // there was an error from the API
            print_r('API returned error: ' . $transaction->message);
            }

            // redirect to page so User can pay
            // echo $transaction->message;

            header('Location: ' . $transaction->data->link); 
}
```

I'm sending my responses with jquery ajax

Comment: You are talking about the browser console? What, that just says "Hosted Link", without anything else? No reference to any particular URL, script, or anything? What have you done so far to try and debug this?

Comment: FYI, any script you are writing today, should really not contain `real_escape_string` any more - you should be using prepared statements.

Comment: ...and also there's no database code here, so it's unclear what purpose you think real_escape_string is serving anyway. But as CBroe says, it's obsolete (by 20 years!)...if you _do_ have some database code, use parameterised queries and prepared statements to build the SQL.

Comment: Anyway what debugging have you done? Where does that output come from? If there is _any_ output from your page before the `header` command, then the `header` command will not work (and should result in an additional warning message too). It's unclear if you're seeing such a warning (or maybe it's in your php error log file instead?), or if you've tried to identify which bit of your script is outputting that "hosted link" text. It doesn't appear that it could come directly from any of the code you've shown here. Please ensure you provide us a [mre] of the stated issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the correction on using real_escape_string, I'm using prepared statements though but I made the silly mistake of using both of them together.
Thanks for that correction.

Also, @ADyson, I intentionally omitted the database codes as I didn't want any storage to database yet, only wanted to see the redirection to the flutterwave checkout page.
There are no error logs.

But I'll check my console again and drop any further clues that may help in the debugging.

Comment: Thanks. Which console are you referring to? Do you mean javascript console in the browser?

Comment: Yes, I'm sending my responses with jqueryajax @ADyson

Comment: That is probably the cause of your problem then. AJAX does not follow Location redirect headers, because the whole point of AJAX is so that the browser can stay on the same page after the request has completed. If you want to redirect after the request, it would probably make more sense to just post back a normal form to PHP instead of using AJAX.

Comment: @ADyson, thank you very much. It works now posting back my form to php instead of using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX does not follow `Location` redirect headers, because the whole point of AJAX is so that the browser can stay on the same page after the request has completed.

If you want to redirect after the request, it would probably make more sense to just post back a normal form to PHP instead of using AJAX.